# Migration from VS2008 to VS 2010 - ContentPlaceHolder Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I had migrated my application from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. Everything works fine. I'm able to compile and run the application. But I can't do any design changes inside my application.

> ERROR CREATING CONTROL - CONTENTPLACEHOLDER1 Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of Object.

How to fix this?

Comment: Any callstack available?

Comment: I cant able to understand....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. In BaseForm, we should check a condition  " if (!this.DesignMode) " in OnInit event. And we should give base.OnInit(e); before that condition

Comment: Is this bug fixed in VS 2010 sp1 or is it still exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset all IDs to your controls, including `ContentPlaceholders` in your master page.

Comment: Yes Done...But Same Error is Coming